# How to detect barcode using Apple Vision in CGRect only?

Tags: ios, swift, barcode-scanner, vision

I have an app that uses a `CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 335, height: 150)` to show the camera for barcode scanning.  However when presented a barcode off camera (not in the CGRect) will get scanned.  How can I limit the area for scanning to the CGRect in my preview layer?  This is using Vision.

```
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
var activeInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!

lazy var detectBarcodeRequest = VNDetectBarcodesRequest { request, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        
        print("Barcode Error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
    
        return
    }
    
    self.processBarCode(request)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    setupSession()
    setupPreview()
    startSession()
}

func setupSession() {
    
    guard let camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else {
        return
        
    }
    do {
        let videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera)
        
        for input in [videoInput] {
            if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                captureSession.addInput(input)
            }
        }
        activeInput = videoInput
    } catch {
        print("Error setting device input: \(error)")
        return
    }
    
    let captureOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    
    captureOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]
    captureOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default))
    
    captureSession.addOutput(captureOutput)

}

func setupPreview() {
    
    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    
    previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
    previewLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 335, height: 150)
    
    view.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, at: 0)

}//setupPreview

func startSession() {
    if !captureSession.isRunning {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async { [weak self] in
            self?.captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - processBarCode
func processBarCode(_ request: VNRequest) {
    
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let results = request.results as? [VNBarcodeObservation] else {
            return
        }
        
        if let payload = results.first?.payloadStringValue, let symbology = results.first?.symbology {
            print("payload is \(payload) \(symbology) ")
            
        }
        
    }
    
}//processBarCode
```

## Edit:

```
// MARK: - AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
extension CameraViewController: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        
        guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
        
        let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(
            cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer,
            orientation: .up)
        
        do {
            try imageRequestHandler.perform([detectBarcodeRequest])
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }//captureOutput
    
}//extension
```

Answer (score 2):

```
extension AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
    func rectOfInterestConverted(parentRect: CGRect, fromLayerRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let parentWidth = parentRect.width
        let parentHeight = parentRect.height
        let newX = (parentWidth - fromLayerRect.maxX)/parentWidth
        let newY = 1 - (parentHeight - fromLayerRect.minY)/parentHeight
        let width = 1 - (fromLayerRect.minX/parentWidth + newX)
        let height = (fromLayerRect.maxY/parentHeight) - newY

        return CGRect(x: newX, y: newY, width: width, height: height)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if let rect = videoPreviewLayer?.rectOfInterestConverted(parentRect: self.view.frame, fromLayerRect: scanAreaView.frame) {
    captureMetadataOutput.rectOfInterest = rect
}
```

Comment: To make this answer as helpful as possible, please add explanation what exactly you doing and why.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a property `regionOfInterest` of `VNDetectBarcodesRequest` to setup a detection region.
The default value is { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 } } according to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnimagebasedrequest/2877482-regionofinterest)

Answer (score 1):

In `func captureOutput(_:didOutput:from:)` you most likely passing whole image into `VNImageRequestHandler`.
Instead you need to crop image to your visible rect.
Another approach would be lock Vision to only visible part of image via `regionOfInterest` as @HurricaneOnTheMoon proposed below.

Comment: I've added the code for captureOutput, I seemed to have forgotten it.  How would I crop the image?